# In Artifactory 5.8.3, Local Helm Repository does not generate index.yaml

Tags: artifactory, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying the latest (5.8.3) version of JFrog Artifactory. Want to use it as Helm Repo, but failed to create one.

The image I'm using is the oss one, docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss. 
Started a brand new container with it;
Created Local Repo and choose Helm as the type. But there is no index.yaml generated in the repo. Tried "Recalculate Index", still nothing there.
Then I created a virtual Repo, chose Helm type and added first local repo in it. When I was trying to add repo with helm client, it complains 404 to index.yaml.

```
$helm repo add helm_interface http://9.21.61.150:32576/artifactory/helm_interface 

Error: Looks like "http://9.21.61.150:32576/artifactory/helm_interface" is not a valid chart 
repository or cannot be reached: Failed to fetch http://9.21.61.150:32576/artifactory/helm_interface/index.yaml : 404 Not Found
```

If I manually create one index.yaml and put into the repo as an artifact, it worked, but that's not what I was expecting.

Did anyone successfully created a Local Helm Repository with the Artifactory and get index.yaml generated?

Comment: I requested a trial license of the pro version and got the same as above...

Comment: as mentioned in the documention helm charts can be resolved only throught virtual repositories. So you need to create a virtual helm repo whch aggregate your local and use your helm client on it.  https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Helm+Chart+Repositories#HelmChartRepositories-ResolvingHelmCharts

Comment: @jroquelaure thanks, it works well by setting up a virtual repo and aggregating it to a pre-setup local helm repo.

Comment: cool, I move my comment as an anwser so if you don't mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as mentioned in the documention helm charts can be resolved only throught virtual repositories. So you need to create a virtual helm repo whch aggregate your local and use your helm client on it. 
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Helm+Chart+Repositories#HelmChartRepositories-ResolvingHelmCharts